# How to get .m file from static library in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can any one tell i lost my macbook data.I have lost some many projects is that laptop.I have create one custom static library.In that i have back up only these folder

```
FolderName
|- libstaticlibrary.a
|-  StaticClass.h
```

So is there any possible to recover .m file from this library and .h class.It will be appreciated if you would give any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

The only option would be to decompile it but you won't get the same .m file as you had before. For example the variable will have different and cryptic names.
Sorry for your loss.

Comment: Thanks for replay.How can i decompile it?